# Add to calendar in windows phone 8 through web

Tags: javascript, php, html

Just like iCal i want to add an event to calendar in windows phone 8 and 8.1 through web is there any way to achieve this ?

Any server side or client side scripting would do as well.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing but wasn't able to find a way to do this. The next best thing was to give an option for the user to add an event to their Outlook.com calendar. You can use the Outlook.com REST API for this, the syntax is http://calendar.live.com/calendar/calendar.aspx?rru=addevent&dtstart=START_DATE_AND_TIME&dtend=END_DATE_AND_TIME&summary=EVENT_TITLE&location=LOCATION_TEXT and the dates need to be in yyyymmddThhmmss format.

Full documentation here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846807.aspx#single